# Getting Coords from database within specified boundaries(map corners)

Tags: php, mysql

I have this field `center`. The data saved are `Longitude_Latitude` of locations. I'm using Google maps JavaScript API and I want to get the coords that are located within the shown map. (I'm using php in the server side).

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uzeiq6043rvueqf/Capture.PNG]
[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lk6g4tucf60n8va/Untitled.png]

My Idea to work this out is to compare center coords with the corner coords.
in order to get location coords

1. `center_Longitude` must be between `TopLeftCoords_Longitude` and `BottomRightCoords_Longitude`
2. `center_Latitude` must be between
   `TopLeftCoords_Latitude` and `BottomRightCoords_Latitude`

The Question is can I do this using MySQL? or do I have to have separate fields for center longitude and latitude?

Comment: It's difficult to tell what you need exactly without the table structure you are using.

Comment: The website does not allow me to put images. I just put links. check them out. I hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unclear about what you are asking, but I gathered you want to separate the `center` field to get the latitude and longitude components. This can be accomplished like so:

```
SELECT 
    LEFT(center, LOCATE('_', center) - 1) AS latitude,
    RIGHT(center, LOCATE('_', center) - 1) AS longitude
FROM earth
```

**Update 1**

Per your comment, you have requested the following criteria:

`IF Lat <= TopLeftLat && Lat >= BottomRightLat && Lon <= TopLeftLon && Lon >= BottomRightLon`

This is your modified query:

```
SELECT
    LEFT(center, LOCATE('_', center) - 1) AS latitude, 
    RIGHT(center, CHAR_LENGTH(center) - LOCATE('_', center) ) AS longitude
FROM realestate
```

Adding the criteria into your query would look something like this (assuming that `TopLeftLat`, etc. are attributes in your table):

```
SELECT a.lat, a.lon
FROM
    (SELECT
        LEFT(center, LOCATE('_', center) - 1) AS lat, 
        RIGHT(center, CHAR_LENGTH(center) - LOCATE('_', center) ) AS lon
    FROM realestate) a
WHERE a.lat <= TopLeftLat AND a.lat >= BottomRightLat AND a.lon <= TopLeftLon AND a.lon >= BottomRightLon
```

Comment: `SELECT 
    LEFT(center, LOCATE('_', center) - 1) AS latitude,
    RIGHT(center, CHAR_LENGTH(center) - LOCATE('_', center) ) AS longitude
FROM realestate`
I modified it a bit. Now it works well.
But How can Filter Lat and Lon so they are only returned 
`IF Lat <= TopLeftLat && Lat >= BottomRightLat && Lon <= TopLeftLon && Lon >= BottomRightLon`

Comment: I really appreciate this. I used your last code and unfortunately it doesnt work. https://www.dropbox.com/s/feqqar3frasz0g2/code.PNG

Comment: I changed the last two operators `<=` `=>` to the opposite `=>` `<=` and now it works perfectly. Thank you so much. I am willing to put the answer in a tidy way in the question so it benefits the others and I will refer it to you. Do you allow me?

Comment: @Sami You can edit my answer and add an **Update 2** at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need separate fields for longitude and latitude. Save the coordinates in your database by using php (never use javascript for that for security reasons!!).

When you have the data in your database, you can either perform math operations there like

```
SELECT SUM(latitude) FROM tablename
```

OR you pull the data from the db and do stuff with it in php, like so:

```
<?php
    $result=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM tablename");
    $entries=array();
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_object($result)) $entries[]=(object) $row;
?>
```

This will save the whole table in an array called `entries`.

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) are some good instructions on how to retrieve data from a db with php.